# The Operation Couldn't be completed. Connection reset by peer In Xcode 8.1

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, ipa, xcode8

While uploading the application to the iTunes connect this error is occurring "The Operation Couldn't be completed. Connection reset by peer".

Same error is occuuring while i try to export the ipa.

I im using XCode 8.1.

[image]

Comment: Xcode is flaky sometimes. That error doesn't make any more sense to me than it does to you. Google that specific message. Somebody else may have figured it out, or it may be that Apple's servers are having a problem. If you can't solve it soon, reach out to Apple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some R&D. No any solution found, then I have removed derived data and restart the Xcode it works completely.

Comment: After i removed the derived data not success.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing the same issue and I just restarted the Xcode and it works :)